# Extrude polygons with holes in GRASS using v.extrude

Tags: grass-gis

I have a shapefile with building footprint polygons. Many of the polygons have holes/inner rings within them (I'm not sure of the correct term in Grass). These import correctly into Grass GIS. I aim to drape the polygons over a DEM, extrude  and export them and the DEM for use in a realtime 3D visualisation.

The following workflow is functional, except where `v.extrude` messes up the geometry:

- import vector (allowing cleaning) and raster data
- set `g.region` to the polygon layer
- drape the polygons on the DEM using `v.drape`
- extrude them using `v.extrude`
- output the layer using `v.out.vtk`

My problem is that the extrusion process ignores the holes in the polygons and creates geometry for the outer ring only. This happens whether or not `v.drape` is used beforehand.

I've tried the following (unsuccessful) ideas already:

- generating centroids for the 'holes' first (this just creates a new polygon 'separate' from the outer ring).
- using `v.clean` with the `chbridge` option, hoping that might add a bridge from outer to inner ring.

Another idea might be to break all the polygons down to triangles first, but I hate to think how complex the 3D geometry would be afterwards! Likewise, manually adding bridging lines to the polygons is not practical given the size of the dataset.

Am I missing something? I'm happy to use Grass and QGIS. Many thanks

Comment: Can you make a minimalistic dataset available for testing?

Comment: Sorry @markusN for the late reply. I can't make the data available. I found that it was a limitation of `v.extrude` and that my data was sound. A possible alternative is converting GML to the 3D format directly.